# How to save Images using custom location using contentResolver.insert() on API level 21/23

Tags: android, android-camera, mediastore

I am currently using the following code to launch the camera and take a photo with custom filename and location:

```
    private fun openCamera() {
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "${fileName}_${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "${relativeFileName}_${getDate(System.currentTimeMillis(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS")}")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image")
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis())
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, System.currentTimeMillis())

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation)

    uri = contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

    val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE_CODE)
}
```

However, this line required `API level 29 annotation`:

```
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, relativeLocation)
```

Specifically `MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH`

I am using SDK 21 (Lollipop) but I am willing to compromise up to SDK 23 (Marshmallow).

Could you please offer me suggestions?

Comment: On Android Q you should indeed use .RELATIVE_PATH. But below Q .DATA with a full path.

Comment: Can you please point me to a link with a guide?

Comment: Click on the `mediastore` button of your post.